# no viable conversion from returned value of type 'basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >' to function return

Tags: c++, c++11, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

I am having this error.

```
no viable conversion from returned value of type       'basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >' to function return       type 'bool'       
return (getline(fin,buf))
```

I will really appreciate any help. I am trying to compile a c++ code. Here is the line of code I have issue with:

```
bool getInstruction( ifstream & fin , string & buf ) {
      return (getline(fin,buf));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that [`std::basic_ios::operator bool`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) is marked as `explicit` (since C++11); the return value of [`getline()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) (which is an instantiation of `std::basic_istream`) can't convert to `bool` implicitly.

You can convert it to `bool` explicitly.

> Returns `true` if the stream has no errors and is ready for I/O operations. Specifically, returns `!fail()`.

e.g.

```
return static_cast<bool>(getline(fin,buf));
```